# Create a DMG using firebreath

Tags: macos, plugins, firebreath, dmg

I have build a plugin using firebreath on MacOSX. I'm stuck at deploying it. I tried to create dmg by including "include(Mac/installer.cmake)" It did build a dmg But im trying to copy the contenets to Library/InternetPlugins directory. Please someone hep me how to write installer and uninstall script for the browser plugin

Comment: If I were you I'd phrase the question less as a plugin question and more as a mac os X installer question.

What you need to do is create a DMG with an installer that copies the plugin into the ~/Library/Internet Plugins directory.  You could do that with a shell script, with an applescript app (that's how we do it), or by including a .pkg.  Those are really not plugin-specific questions, though

Comment: I tried editing the applescript provided by the firebreath which is available in Mac/ folder when i try to run it it doesn't run. I want to wrap the installer in dmg itself. when i try to create a dmg without any changes to applescript i got the dmg which is able to mount but doesnt copy files to /library/internetplugins folder. My question may sound really stupid but im quite new to all this. I'm stuck here

Answer (score 1):

I've tested many ways: drag'n drop installer, AppleScript, various packaging products. AppleScript was the winner in my case.

Basically you need to create a DMG which contains AppleScript (converted to App). This script copies the plugin to ~/Internet Plug-Ins  and restarts browser if needed.